# How to take serial number input from user in excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim a As String, bInvalid As Boolean, CurrDate As Date
CurrDate = Date
  a = InputBox("Enter the Row", "Please enter the row number", "Please enter data")
  If IsNumeric(a) Then
    If a > 0 Then
      Rows(a).Select
          Selection.Copy
          Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
          Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
          Range("L" & a).ClearContents
          Rows(a + 1).Select
          Range("S" & a).Value = CurrDate + 1
          Selection.Rows.Group
          ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1
    Else
      bInvalid = True
    End If
  Else
    ' If the user presses Cancel, then a=""
    If a <> "" Then bInvalid = True
  End If
  If bInvalid Then MsgBox "Please enter a valid row number"
End Sub
```

[image]

Currently I'm taking row inputs from the user, but as you can see in the image I want to take sr.no as an input from the user like c1, c2, so is there a way the above code can be modified and work on the sr.no input rather than the row?

Comment: I cannot make any sense out of your question. Could you please clarify? "modified and work on" does not mean much.

Comment: Hi @braX Sure, I'm currently taking rows as an input from user like 5,6 or whatever be the row number user want to give, But instead of taking row as an input I want to take the serial number as an input I mean the rows should be selected on the basis of s.no so for example if I give C1 as an input(refer above image) then row 5 should get selected automatically.

Comment: So you are asking how to have the user enter `C1` and then it will search for it automatically and return the row number?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Comment: @braX Yes thats exactly what I'm searching, But unable to implement it on the above code

Comment: Well i gave you a link to the `Find` method which you can use to modify your code accordingly.

Comment: You simply need to loop down the srno column until you find the supplied serial number and then perform the insertion and copying.

Comment: Tried finding the serial number via find function it pops an error I dont know how to figure this out but yes thanks for the help guys. Will let it run over the rows for now as I'm unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim a As String, bInvalid As Boolean, CurrDate As Date, X As Integer
CurrDate = Date
a = InputBox("Enter the RFI number", "Please enter the RFI number", "Please enter data")
    Cells.Find(What:=a, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:= _
        xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
        , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    X = ActiveCell.Row
    Rows(X).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("L" & X).ClearContents
    Rows(X + 1).Select
    Selection.Rows.Group
    ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels RowLevels:=1

End Sub
```

This works. Thankyou.